# Should the review limit be determined by the user's pass/fail audit ratio?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

The current system gives *everyone* a maximum review limit of 20 posts/votes/edits per day (except for the CV queue, which is at 40/day). This means *users who have a history of failing audits* get their 20/day (if not banned), and *users who consistently pass audits* also get 20/day.

So, instead of having the same hard limit for the "less sharpened" reviewer and the "better" reviewer, why not determine the number of reviews a user is allowed to do based on their audit history?

That is, *reduce* the limit for less able reviewers (and robo-reviewers) and *increase* it for good reviewers.

For example, the algorithm for the all the queues *could* be like this (the numbers are only suggestions),

```
limit = (10 * ((audits_passed + 1) / (audits_failed + 1)))

if (limit > 50)
{
    limit = 50;
}
```

For the queues that are backlogged (i.e, the CV queue), maybe the `10 *` could be replaced with `15 *` (and the maximum limit could go up to 75)?

Comment: @Payeli Hmm, but I'm suggesting we make the "Hard Limit" variable based on the user's audit history, which is not how the current system works (according to that post).

Comment: @VotetoClose I'm proposing we lessen the limit only for users with a poor audit history and increase it for users with a good history.

Comment: @Sam: You're going to get a `divide-by-zero` exception (sorry for being pedantic).

Comment: @JonEgerton Lol, happy now?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea!

Comment: Any updates on this? I passed the 20 reviews limit and it's still counting today. I'm already at 25, not sure if it's a bug or a feature.

Comment: Interesting. It makes sense to reduce the limit for those with poor audit history in my opinion. (Provided that, as they get better at it, their limit can be increased again.) However, I don't think people good at reviewing should see their limit increased. I see it as encouraging working extra time; in the short term it *may* get things done, in the medium/long run, performance will eventually degrade. No matter how good they are, air traffic controllers are required to take breaks at regular intervals. I think a similar argument could be made here too.