# Can the limit of 20 reviews per day be increased as you gain experience?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, reputation

Once a user earns 500 Reputation, he or she is able to access the review queues for "Triage", "Late Answers", and "First Posts". However, he or she is limited to 20 reviews for each category per day.

Can we increase the review limit as you gain more experience? I know that the review limit doesn't apply to moderators, but it should increase as a normal user gets better at reviewing.

A trusted user can earn up to 100 total flags per day, and the amount of flags someone can raise depends on how many flags are accepted. He or she can also earn a bonus flag every 2000 Reputation points.

I suggest something similar for reviews. The reviewer should have their review limit increased by 1 every time they pass 5 audits. He or she can also earn reviews by giving better feedback in the "First Posts" queue.

This will benefit the community because it allows good users to contribute more by reviewing, just like how good users are allowed to flag more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been proven time and time again that having a lot of reputation doesn't make one a good reviewer.  There have been countless cases of users with tens of thousands of rep being robo reviewers, or otherwise doing a bad job of reviewing.  Beyond a certain (reasonably small) point (which we attempt to set as the rep requirement to access the queue), reputation simply ceases to correlate with the quality of the reviews.

Comment: What about passing audits? I mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @NarawaGames then look at [the duplicate link I provided](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262436/should-the-review-limit-be-determined-by-the-users-pass-fail-audit-ratio)

Comment: @NarawaGames Audits are there to make sure that you're at least reading the question and aren't clicking a button without paying the least big of attention.  They don't necessarily mean you're actually a good reviewer.  They just aren't designed to test that.